# Can't streaming TS File

Tags: video-streaming, google-cast

I wrote a app for Android, so that I can stream files from my SAT-Receiver. Files like mkv (copied from my PC) working without problems (except files with DTS -> I hope this will be come with the next updates).

But when I want to stream ts files (recorded files from the Sat-Receiver) my Chromecast load & load or crash. The debugger console from my Chromecast, return me: Faild to load Metadata.

Because the mkv file works from the same place without problems, I think, that there is a problem with the TS files.

You find a example TS file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7pcAkvWOZoNZ0RsSVVUUFNrZlk/view

Perhaps somebody can explain me, why the file makes problems.

**EDIT**

this is the answer from Google:

> Playing ts files directly in an HTML video element is not supported at
>   this time. However, ts files that are part of an HLS stream is
>   supported. For more details on supported media, please refer to this
>   link: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

**But how I make a HLS Stream?**

Comment: Add answer from Google.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to create a hls stream, you can use ffmpeg to do so:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "test.ts" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v copy -async 1 -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 999 "hls\output.m3u8"
```

The output will be a .m3u8 file together with a lot of small .ts files, in this case 10 seconds each. I use `-c:a copy -c:v copy` so it will not transcode.